# Javascript conflict in header vs footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, footer, conflict

I have two javascript scripts I want to use, a clickable dropdown menu and slick.js for an image slideshow. The clickable dropdown menu only works if placed in the header, and slick only works if placed in footer....and they both end up conflicting each other, one overriding the other depending on where the javascript library is called. For example, the following code would only show the slideshow:

HEADER:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // Clickable Dropdown
            $('.menu-main-menu-container > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
            $('..menu-main-menu-container .js ul').hide();
            $('.menu-main-menu-container .js').click(function(e) {
                $('.menu-main-menu-container .js ul').slideToggle(200);
                $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $(document).click(function() {
                if ($('.menu-main-menu-container .js ul').is(':visible')) {
                    $('.menu-main-menu-container .js ul', this).slideUp();
                    $('.menu-main-menu-container').removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

FOOTER:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/js/slick.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slideshow-images').slick({

        });
    });
</script>
```

And as soon as I remove "jquery-1.11.0.min.js" from the footer the dropdown menu starts working again. How can I get both to work simultaneously?

Comment: only load jQuery library once in page, before any dependent plugins and code. Also no reason to load 2 versions of your slick plugin, just use the `.min` version

Comment: if I load jQuery just once, it doesn't work on the dropdown menu for some reason...any idea why?

Comment: Did you load it before the dropdown code?

Comment: You also have an extra `.` here: `$('..menu-main-menu-container `

Answer (score 0):

You only need to load jQuery once.

The reason it stops working is because when you load it a second time, the original jQuery object is overwritten and no longer valid. However, the code that's already been executed in your header is tied to the original object, which means that it doesn't work when the click event is triggered.

Solution: only load jQuery once.